# Creating app to test email design on different devices

Tags: email, testing, rendering, visualization

Recently I was faced with the task of creating an app which will test the look of a new email design on different devices and mail clients.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to implement such a solution? 
What Im looking for is something similar to this : http://mailchimp.com/features/inbox-inspector/

How can I implement something similar? 
Maybe something based on system virtualization (possibly combination of vmware machines)?

Or application just knows the differences in rendering and visualize them (it's not actually testing, is it ?)

I have to say that i'm a bit in the blind spot, and have no other ideas then those mentioned above.

Thanks